# How can I add a button under Additional Cache Management?

Tags: adminhtml, design

Magento's cache page (accessible via `System` → `Cache Management`) has a section titled `Additional Cache Management`.

Is there a way that I can add my own button to this page without creating a copy of that template file & customizing it? In other words - can it be done programmatically somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can create button programmatically.
Put below code in your admin moduel layout.xml file

```
 <adminhtml_cache_index>
    <reference name="cache.additional">
        <block type="core/template" name="your unique name" template="modulename/cache/additional.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_cache_index>
```

Just add button html in additional.phtml file